# Find direction of a point from other fixed point

Tags: android, directions

I have a question here, how can i find the direction of a particular point from fixed point. For example, from my current location in Google Maps, I want to know the direction of a particular point. How can i achieve this. Can any one guide me regarding to this. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code::**

```
//calling method from onCreate() method
```

String pairs[] = getDirectionData(sourceLat,sourceLong, destinationLat, destinationLong );

```
private String[] getDirectionData(String sourceLat, String sourceLong,
            String destinationLat, String destinationLong) {

        String urlString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&" + "saddr="
                + sourceLat + "," + sourceLong + "&daddr=" + destinationLat
                + "," + destinationLong + "&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml";
        Log.d("URL", urlString);
        Document doc = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        String pathConent = "";

        try {

            url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineString");
        for (int s = 0; s < nl.getLength(); s++) {
            Node rootNode = nl.item(s);
            NodeList configItems = rootNode.getChildNodes();
            for (int x = 0; x < configItems.getLength(); x++) {
                Node lineStringNode = configItems.item(x);
                NodeList path = lineStringNode.getChildNodes();
                pathConent = path.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }
        String[] tempContent = pathConent.split(" ");
        return tempContent;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Actually what i need is, i tried android device heading(directions) by using sensors. So, how can i find the direction of a point from my current position by using sensor. Is there any possibility to do this or any suggestion.

Comment: what kinds of sensor are u want to use?